# Why does sometimes DateTime.TryParse work and other time only DateTime.ParseExact work?

Tags: c#

I have two laptops both with windows xp sp3, vs 2010 and target framework .Net 3.5. When processing DateTime variable, I found that with laptop1

```
DateTime oldOrderDate;
string strnewdate = string.Empty;
CultureInfo provider = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

if (DateTime.TryParse(items[1], out oldOrderDate))                                    
    strnewdate = oldOrderDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

returned an exception "string was not recognized as a valid datetime" , but the codes below:

```
oldOrderDate = DateTime.ParseExact(items[1], "dd/MM/yyyy", provider);
strnewdate = oldOrderDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

works. OTOH, with laptop2,

```
oldOrderDate = DateTime.ParseExact(items[1], "dd/MM/yyyy", provider);
strnewdate = oldOrderDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

returned an exception "string was not recognized as a valid datetime" , but the code below:

```
if (DateTime.TryParse(items[1], out oldOrderDate))                                    
    strnewdate = oldOrderDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
```

works. So, my question is how I should do processing of a DateTime variable to work in both laptops. I'd really appreciate any advice you could give me. Thank's in advance.

Comment: You know you can get the best of both worlds with [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx)

Comment: It would be great to see examples of the string that you are trying to parse. I would also check what the language is on each machine.

Comment: The general answer is probably that the date you provided doesn't match what is parsible by each method. `ParseExact` will strictly parse your date based on the format provided while `TryParse` is looser (and arguably) smarter because it knows a variety of standard formats. The `Try`* methods tend to be preferred though.

Comment: Agreed you are likely getting different strings on each machine out of items[1]. Then differing language settings on each machine cause the TryParse to succeed or fail depending on if they happen to match what is in items[1]

Comment: Thank you. TryParseExact did it.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but look at the regional settings of date and time in control panel. In my systems they also differ and hence different results.